# How to post a request and get response from Spring REST controller by Wicket ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, wicket

I want to develop a simple web application, where you can calculate percentages, like on this page:
http://www.percentagecalculator.net/

I am writing my frontend using wicket, and the REST has to be Spring:

The PercentageModel is:

```
public class PercentageModel {
    private int percentage;
    private int fullValue;
    private int percentagedValue;
    //getter/setter/constructors...
}
```

The spring RESTful controller should be something like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/percentController")
public class PercentController {

    @Autowired
    private PercentageCalculator percentageCalculator;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public PercentageModel calculate(PercentageModel model) {
        return percentageCalculator.calculate(model);
    }

}
```

The calculator spring bean is:

```
@Controller
public class PercentageCalculator {

    public PercentageModel calculate(PercentageModel request) {
        PercentageModel response = new PercentageModel();
        //it calculates everything, and set the values for the response
        return response;
    }

}
```

And the wicket submit link is:

```
form.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("calculate") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        super.onSubmit(target, form);
        PercentageModel percentageModelRequest = (PercentageModel) form.getModelObject();
        //how to call the spring controller here with the PercentageModel request
    }
});
```

That is all I have already finished. Now I am in a little trouble. First of all, I am new in spring and REST. The question here is:

How can I call the REST controller from wicket ajax? Examples would be really great!

Also, should I make some interesting changes to the web.xml? This is it now:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">   
    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicketfilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>myapp.WicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicketfilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And do I need another XML-s, or anything? And anyway, is my already written code good? Or should I change somethings inside the spring beans maybe?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have the feeling that this code is in a single application. If this is the case then you don't need the controller, you can just use the Spring bean in your Wicket code.

Comment: But the task here is to make it RESTful. I know, Spring bean would be easier, but unfortunatelly I have to make it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any HTTP client library, like Apache CXF, Retrofit, etc., to make the REST call.

There is no need to create `PercentageModel` instance at all. Just pass the raw data as path/query string parameters to the REST endpoint.

Make sure you do synchronous HTTP calls!